# Primefaces: dynamic content refresh issue

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, graphicimage, commandbutton

I have a webapp where I select some content to be deleted. A modal pops-up displaying a preview of the image/flash selected. I hit a button and everything works fine. But, when I select another content to be deleted, the modal pops-up and, for a microsecond, it displays the previously deleted file which is then replaced by the new content I want to delete.

The code for showing the dynamic content is as follows:

**For images:**

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{controller.tempImage}" height="110" 
    id="imageID" />
```

**For flash:**

```
<p:media value="#{controller.tempImage}" width="110" height="110" 
    id="imageID" player="flash" />
```

**Controller:**

```
public StreamedContent getTempImage() {
    try {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context.getRenderResponse() ) {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        }
        else {              
                tempImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream("pathToFile"), "image/jpeg");                
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        tempImage = new DefaultStreamedContent();
    }

    return tempImage;
}
```

I tried setting `tempImage` to null before loading and `autoUpdate=true` in the modal but no luck.

**Delete button** (the one that shows the delete modal):

```
<p:commandButton id="btnDelete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteModal.show();"  actionListener="#{controller.initDelete}" update=":deleteForm">
```

**Delete form (xhtml):**

```
<h:form  id="deleteForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<p:dialog id="deleteDialog" widgetVar="deleteModal" modal="true" resizable="false" draggable="false" autoUpdate="true">
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="false" >
            <p:panelGrid id="panelId">
                <p:row>                 
                    <p:column>
                        <p:panelGrid id="bannerPanel">

                            <p:row>
                                <p:column>
                                 <p:graphicImage value="#{controller.tempImage}" height="110" id="imageID" />
                                </p:column>
                            </p:row>    

                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>  
                                <p:commandButton id="doDeleteBtn" value="Delete"
                                     actionListener="#{controller.delete}" >                                                        
                                </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </f:facet>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Can you show code for that button?

Comment: It would be helpful to see more code... maybe the button that shows the dialog and the dialog itself (xhtml) and the method that deletes the content (bean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change from:

```
onclick="deleteModal.show();"
```

to:

```
oncomplete="deleteModal.show();"
```

This will ensure that your dialog is viewed after AJAX request is completed, not before it is started.

You should use `onclick`, when you are creating so called **push buttons**, the buttons with `type="button"`, which are just executing some JavaScript. Default type of buttons in Primefaces is `submit`.

Comment: Yep. That's it. Thanks a lot for your help, again :P. You've been very much helpful.

Comment: By the way (I dunno if I can ask here)... I constantly get the warning `JSF1091 No mime type could be found for file dynamiccontent` and I've followed a few tutorials posted here and in some PF forums but no change. Do you have any idea about this issue? It appears to be quite common but I can't get rid of it.

Comment: @partlov, you're quick! ;)